# How do you iterate over all cells and not just the first cell?

Tags: python

I'm trying to update all applicable values in a column. The code only seems to change the first cell to "1". How does Python iterate over all cells in the column?

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('Workbook')
ws = wb['A']

for cell in ws['E']:
    if cell.value > 1:
        cell.value = 1

    else:
        cell.value = ""

    wb.save('Workbook2')
    wb.close()
```

Comment: Are the other cell values larger than 1?  Did you print the value of `ws[`E`]`? Is it a list or tuple?

Comment: I am not familar with openpyxl, but `wb.save(...); wb.close()` looks very wrong *within the loop* - you are closing the workbook after processing the first cell.

Comment: @roadrunner66 The cell values are either blank or larger than 1. When printing the column values will print one at a time vertically. 

Yes, the loop is wrong, it'll simply make the values of the first several cells "1" - even the blank cells.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to import openpyxl to open a workbook. Pandas has a read_excel() function that does the job using the openpyxl engine.

From there, you can use either the function iterrow() or iteritems() to iterate through the rows and columns using the index easily. This would be more traditional, but slow. A better faster method would be to use the apply function as shown below.

After which, you'd simply need to the save the dataframe back into the workbook/worksheet you took from

```
df = pd.read_excel('Workbook.xlsx', engine="openpyxl")
print(df["E"])
df["E"] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x["E"]>1 else x["E"], axis=1)
print(df["E"])
```

You can read more about iter function in the pd docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

You can read more about the apply function there as well: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html